# Docusign API Multiple required radio groups

Tags: docusignapi

My application allows multiple sales quotes to go out in a single pdf packet.  At the bottom of each quote is an Accept (quote#) Decline (quote#) radio group.  Using the DocuSign API I am attaching a radio group to each of these accept/decline sections on each quote.  There is no "required" option at the group level so I set "required" on one of the radio's which makes the group required.

This all works great except the signing flow through the document.  If I choose "Accept" which is the first radio and hit "Next" it changes to "Choose" and seems to want me to choose "Decline" as well.  If I hit "Choose" it moves on to the next radio group.  If I choose "Decline" it moves on to the next radio group as it should (I assume because its the last radio item in the group).  If I am at the last radio group I can choose "Accept" and its finished.

It seems like a bug to me since you can only choose a single radio group item, doing so with required should fulfill this requirement with any selection.  I would like it to move on to the next radio group after either selection.  Has anyone run into this issue and found a work around or solution?

```
for (var i = 0; i < parts.Count; i++) {

Radio approve = new Radio();
approve.AnchorString = "Accept " + parts[i].Substring(0,parts[i].Length-3) + "-" + parts[i].Substring(parts[i].Length-2,2);             approve.Value = "Accept";
approve.Required = "true";
approve.AnchorMatchWholeWord = "true";
approve.AnchorUnits = "pixels";
approve.AnchorXOffset = "-19";
approve.AnchorYOffset = "-4";

Radio decline = new Radio();
decline.AnchorString = "Decline " + parts[i].Substring(0,parts[i].Length-3) + "-" + parts[i].Substring(parts[i].Length-2,2);                decline.Value = "Decline";                  
decline.AnchorMatchWholeWord = "true";
decline.AnchorUnits = "pixels";
decline.AnchorXOffset = "-19";
decline.AnchorYOffset = "-4";                   

List<Radio> radioVals = new List<Radio>();
radioVals.Add(approve);
radioVals.Add(decline);

RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup();                   
rg.GroupName = parts[i].Substring(0,parts[i].Length-3) + "-" + parts[i].Substring(parts[i].Length-2,2);
rg.Radios = radioVals;              

signer.Tabs.RadioGroupTabs.Add(rg);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the actual values of the GroupName that you are assigning. We are not aware of what `parts[i].Substring(0,parts[i].Length-3) + "-" + parts[i].Substring(parts[i].Length-2,2)` will look like so its hard to provide an answer.

Comment: I have just solved this.  I was looking at it as an API issue when I didn't need too.  I ended up sending a document manually and had the same issue, when tabbing through it would tab through each radio.  I discovered that its a simple admin change.  I just need to change the signing navigation to "Navigate Blank Required Fields".  It turns out this is the recommended setting if your using radio buttons.  Now when I choose "Accept" which is the first radio in the required radio group it moves on to the next required radio group as expected.  Thank you for taking the time to comment!

Answer (score 0):

Please see the DocuSign blog post [Guide Your Signers Through Documents with the Auto-Navigation Feature](https://www.docusign.com/blog/quick-tip-tuesday-guide-your-signers-through-documents-with-the-auto-navigation-feature/)